# share data between two models flutter

Tags: flutter, http, dart, dio

My app fetch some posts from a REST API and these posts come with the following data:{
title, photo,userID...
}
The thing I want to do is instead of displaying the **userID**, I want the **user name**. I thought of maybe passing the id from the post model to the user model but I dont know how to do it and I dont know if that the best method.

**User Model**

```
class User {

String id;
String name;
String email;
String createdAt;


User(
  {
  this.id,
  this.name,
  this.createdAt,
  this.email
  });

User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
id = json['_id'];
name = json['name'];
email = json['email'];
createdAt = json['createdAt'];
}

 Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
data['_id'] = this.id;
data['name'] = this.name;
data['email'] = this.email;
data['createdAt'] = this.createdAt;
return data;
}
 }
```

**Post model**

```
class Post {
 String user;
   String id;
   String title;
  String content;
  String address;
  String category;
  String price;
  String photo;

Post(
  {this.user,
  this.title,
  this.category,
  this.content,
  this.address,
  this.price,
  this.id,
  this.photo});

 Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
id = json['_id'];
title = json['title'];
price = json['price'];
user = json['user'];
content = json['content'];
category = json['category'];
address = json['address'];
photo = json['photo'];
 }

 Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
data['id'] = this.id;
data['title'] = this.title;
data['price'] = this.price;
data['user'] = this.user;
data['content'] = this.content;
data['category'] = this.category;
data['address'] = this.address;
return data;
}
 }
```

**Home Screen** where I want to display the user name

```
 AutoSizeText(
  reversedList[index].user,
   style: TextStyle(
  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
  fontSize: 18),
   )
```

Comment: can you add your restapi result

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right you just need to have a User object (with your User.fromJson) and inject it to the Post initialization.

Like so:

```
final user = User.fromJson(jsonUser);
final post = Post.fromJson(jsonPost..['user']=user.name);
//like this you don't need to refactor anything for now
```

A better approach would be create another class with the specific parameters you expect like the post and the name.
Since I don't really know wich ones are they, you could do like this:

```
class UserPostModel{
  final User user;
  final Post post;
  UserPostModel(this.user,this.post);
}
```

With this approach the AutoSizeText can be mounted as bellow:

```
final userPost = UserPost(user, post);
return AutoSizeText(
  reversedList[index].user.name,
  style: TextStyle(
  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
  fontSize: 18),
);
```

Feel free to ask again with that's not your case.